# Blazor Navigationmanager cancel navigation on locationchanged

Tags: c#, .net-core, navigation, blazor, blazor-webassembly

## Question:

Is there a way on Blazor to cancel navigation?

Let's supose a siple `a href` like this:

```html
<a href="/some/other/blazor/spa/page">Go</a>
```

I would like to cancel navigation (for example if we are editing a form)

## What I have tried.

#### Via JS

I set `onbeforeunload` dom delegate via JSInterop:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        return 'Vols abandonar aquesta pàgina?';
      };
```

but blazor bypass it.

#### Via locationchanged

I tried unsuccessfully to intercept navigation on `locationchanged` event:

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

...

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
}

private void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel Navigation Here
}

public void Dispose()
{
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality was added in .NET 7, the documentation can be found in the ['Handle/prevent location changes'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handleprevent-location-changes) section of the 'Routing and navigation' page.

The example below from that documentation shows code to handle the navigation commencing (in the `OnLocationChanging` method) and then cancels that navigation (with `context.PreventNavigation()`) if the user tries to navigate to the counter page:

> ```
> NavigationManager Navigation
>
> <p>
>     <button @onclick="@(() => Navigation.NavigateTo("/"))">
>         Home (Allowed)
>     </button>
>     <button @onclick="@(() => Navigation.NavigateTo("/counter"))">
>         Counter (Prevented)
>     </button> </p>
>
> @code {
>     private IDisposable? registration;
>
>     protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
>     {
>         if (firstRender)
>         {
>             registration = 
>                 Navigation.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(OnLocationChanging);
>         }
>     }
>
>     private ValueTask OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
>     {
>         if (context.TargetLocation == "/counter")
>         {
>             context.PreventNavigation();
>         }
>
>         return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
>     }
>
>     public void Dispose() => registration?.Dispose(); }
> ```

Comment: Are you so kind to add to your answer a code snipped with an example?

Answer (score 5):

Currently no, this feature is being discussed for .NET V5 - and has a community contribution pull-request so hopefully will make it in. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/24417

The page is not changed when you navigate in Blazor, so there is no unload in order to trigger onbeforeunload.

Comment: _"has a community contribution pull-request so hopefully will make it in."_ 

Comment: short update to this: it's expected to be available with .net 6

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this will be waiting until .net 7 at the soonest.

Comment: Hi Peter, maybe this feature is already available? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handleprevent-location-changes

Answer (score 1):

Update to @PeterMorris answer.

As of 2021-05-17 a location changing event for `NavigationManger` is now committed for `.NET 6.0`. I hope it will be possible to catch this event on a global level in the application.

[image]

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14962

Comment: @daniherrera Haha late night coding. Fixed it now :)

Answer (score -2):

have you tried to put your js file in the index.html or _host.cshtml page ?